# protractor loading or referring to 3rd party JS library in the test

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I am using the protractor to test the angular js application and I have used those 3rd party JS in the application.

I have used a fusion chart, charts js and a few more.

to test those in the protractor spec file

var env = require('C:/DSP/lab/fusion_chart_testing/test/fusioncharts-suite-xt-latest/js/fusioncharts.js');

describe(' chart ', function() {

```
it('chart', function() {

    browser.get("http://127.0.0.1:3000/WebContent/project.html");

    expect('false').toBeTruthy();


});
```

});

am trying to use those JS but it's giving me an error **" Error: ReferenceError: document is not defined"**

the reason is in protractor its element(....).

do i need to change in 3rd party JS or any other way to load this 3rd part js and use them in test.

Comment: FusionCharts needs a document or window object to render. If you are looking to run a test on the charts you can use FusionCharts life cycle events to run your tests, take a look at this link for all supported events  -  https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-events

Comment: do you have or have a reference  sample using these links how I can use it in the protractor test framework